# Script to check CPU, memory, server type

Tags: sql-server, scripting, powershell

Can someone please help me with the script to get CPU, total physical memory, server type(i.e. physical/VM), *maxdop* and *max server memory* details? I need it to run for 50 servers. All the servers are in the same domain. So connectivity is not an issue. A PowerShell solution would be appreciated.

Please let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: Further details needed...what have you tried or written so far?

Comment: I was thinking of a script using CMS but have to go through a painful process of registering all the servers. So I was thinking if powershell can help here and if someone has ready made script available. I'll try what Paul suggested.

Comment: [Add the servers to CMS with PowerShell](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2658/using-powershell-to-register-all-sql-instances-into-central-management-server/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a PowerShell user, but it seems you might be looking for [SQL Power Doc](https://sqlpowerdoc.codeplex.com/) listed on CodePlex and licensed under the Microsoft Public License (Ms-PL), so you are free to create derivative works.

It was written by [Kendal Van Dyke](http://www.kendalvandyke.com/), a well-known and highly respected SQL Server community member.

From the home page:

> SQL Power Doc is a collection of Windows PowerShell scripts and modules that discover, document, and diagnose SQL Server instances and their underlying Windows OS & machine configurations. SQL Power Doc works with all versions of SQL Server from SQL Server 2000 through 2014, and all versions of Windows Server and consumer Windows Operating Systems from Windows 2000 and Windows XP through Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 8. SQL Power Doc is also capable of documenting Windows Azure SQL Databases.